# Converting datetime from character to POSIXct object

Tags: r, datetime, date-formatting, posixct, strptime

I have an instrument that exports data in an unruly time format. I need to combine the `date` and `time` vectors into a new `datetime` vector in the following `POSIXct` format: `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`. Out of curiosity, I attempted to do this in three different ways, using `as.POSIXct()`, `strftime()`, and `strptime()`. When using my *example data* below, only the `as.POSIXct()` and `strftime()` functions work, but I am curious as to why `strptime()` is producing `NAs`? Also, I cannot convert the `strftime()` output into a `POSIXct` object using `as.POSIXct()`...

When trying these same functions on my *real data* (of which I've only provided you with the first for rows), I am running into an entirely different problem. Only the `strftime()` function is working. For some reason the `as.POSIXct()` function is also producing `NAs`, which is the only command I actually need for converting my `datetime` into a `POSIXct` object...

It seems like there are subtle differences between these functions, and I want to know how to use them more effectively. Thanks!

**Reproducible Example:**

```
## Creating dataframe:
date <- c("2017-04-14", "2017-04-14","2017-04-14","2017-04-14")
time <- c("14:24:24.992000","14:24:25.491000","14:24:26.005000","14:24:26.511000")
value <- c("4.106e-06","4.106e-06","4.106e-06","4.106e-06")
data <- data.frame(date, time)
data <- data.frame(data, value) ## I'm sure there is a better way to combine three vectors...
head(data)

## Creating 3 different datetime vectors:

## This works in my example code, but not with my real data... 
data$datetime1 <- as.POSIXct(paste(data$date, data$time), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")
class(data$datetime1)

## This is producing NAs, and I'm not sure why:
data$datetime2 <- strptime(paste(data$date, data$time), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%:%S", tz = "UTC") 
class(data$datetime2)

## This is working just fine
data$datetime3 <- strftime(paste(data$date, data$time), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%:%S", tz = "UTC")
class(data$datetime3)
head(data)

## Since I cannot get the as.POSIXct() function to work with my real data, I tried this workaround. Unfortunately I am running into trouble...
data$datetime4 <- as.POSIXct(x$datetime3, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%:%S", tz = "UTC")
```

**Link to real data**:
[here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By6o_bZ8CGwuT0RoVDJ0bVZFcWs)

**Example using *real_data.txt*:**

```
## Reading in the file:
fpath <- "~/real_data.txt"
x <- read.csv(fpath, skip = 1, header = FALSE, sep = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(x) <- c("date","time","bscat","scat_coef","pressure_mbar","temp_K","CH1","CH2") ## This is data from a Radiance Research Integrating Nephelometer Model M903 for anyone who is interested!

## If anyone could get this to work that would be awesome!
x$datetime1 <- as.POSIXct(paste(x$date, x$time), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%:%S", tz = "UTC") 

## This still doesn't work...
x$datetime2 <- strptime(paste(x$date, x$time), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%:%S", tz = "UTC") 

 ## This works: 
x$datetime3 <- strftime(paste(x$date, x$time), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%:%S", tz = "UTC")

## But I cannot convert from strftime character to POSIXct object, so it doesn't help me at all... 
x$datetime4 <- as.POSIXct(x$datetime3, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%:%S", tz = "UTC")    

head(x)
```

**Solution:**

I was not providing the `as.POSIXct()` function with the correct format string. Once I changed `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M%:%S` to `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`, the `data$datetime2`, `data$datetime4`, `x$datetime1` and `x$datetime2` were working properly! Big thanks to `PhilC` for debugging!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For your real data issue replace the `%m%` with `%m`:

```
## Reading in the file:
fpath <- "c:/r/data/real_data.txt"
x <- read.csv(fpath, skip = 1, header = FALSE, sep = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(x) <- c("date","time","bscat","scat_coef","pressure_mbar","temp_K","CH1","CH2") ## This is data from a Radiance Research Integrating Nephelometer Model M903 for anyone who is interested!

## issue was the %m% - fixed
x$datetime1 <- as.POSIXct(paste(x$date, x$time), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC") 

## Here too - fixed
x$datetime2 <- strptime(paste(x$date, x$time), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC") 
head(x)
```

Comment: **THANK YOU!** My brain was playing tricks on me! For some reason I just wasn't able to see it, but now that you've pointed it out, it's so obvious! Haha I think I'm going to take a break now...

Answer (score 1):

There was a format string error causing the NAs; try this:

```
## This is no longer producing NAs:
data$datetime2 <- strptime(paste(data$date, data$time), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC") 
class(data$datetime2)
```

Comment: Oops, that was a typo on my part, thanks for spotting that!. I fixed my example. That being said, the actual script I was using was formatted correctly and is still producing NAs.

Comment: I ran the corrected version with no error.  There was a hidden character in the function call that was contributing to the error.  If you cut/paste from the answer it should run (it did for me).  pc

Comment: Wow! Yeah this is working for me! When you say hidden character, you mean there's code not being displayed in my original script that is affecting my datetime conversion? Now I just need to find a way to get this to work with my *real_data.txt* example...

Answer (score 0):

Formatting to "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS" is a generic view. To make the fractional seconds to a specific number of decimals call the option for degits.sec, e.g.:

```
options(digits.secs=6) # This will take care of seconds up to 6 decimal points
data$datetime1 <- lubridate::parse_date_time(data$datetime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
```